# How to achieve actual sliding effect in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am animating a menu here 
http://jsfiddle.net/BGV2Z/14/

```
    $("li").on('mouseenter', function () {

        $(this).find('ul').first().css('display', 'none').slideDown(500, function () {

            $(this).css('display', 'block');

        });

    }).on('mouseleave', function () {

        $(this).find('ul').first().slideUp(500, function () {

            $(this).css('display', 'none');

        });
    });
```

and it works fine , the issue I have is that the slideUP/slideDown animation is simply growing the ul element back and forth. What I am after is this here

http://www.joomlatemplates.youjoomla.info/yougrids/

hover over last 3 top menu items.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Change the display position using a `3dtransform`.

Comment: Is what you're after a separated menu? If so, do what @Mathletics said.

Comment: @Mathletics any example?

Comment: So, you can figure this out by inspecting the DOM on that page, but they are doing essentially the same thing you're doing, except the lists aren't nested. The slideout section is at the bottom of the page (in the DOM) and then absolutely positioned. The container has a 0 height and then when it's slide out, a margin on the contents is shifted to create the _illusion_ of sliding. This will be a lot harder with nested lists.

Comment: [Here's a super rough example to get you going](http://jsfiddle.net/BGV2Z/18/).

Comment: I achieved the slide http://jsfiddle.net/BGV2Z/19/, fighting the page z-index from  menu z-index to hide slide from top until the menu is reached. Must keep JS ,  supporting none css3 browsers